# How to map path to route?

Tags: ember.js, url-routing

This is part of my router:

```
this.resource('phoneNumbers', function () {

    this.resource('locators', function () {
        this.route('index');
        this.route('new');
        this.route('show',   { path: '/:locator_id/show' });
        this.route('edit',   { path: '/:locator_id/edit' });
    });

    this.resource('phonelocations', function () {
        this.route('index');
    });

});
```

Sometimes I need to do the following:

1. User clicks edit button
2. I catch the currentPath: `phoneNumbers.locators.index`
3. An edit form is shown, with a `cancel` button
4. If the cancel button is clicked, I want to transition to the old route, using the catched `currentPath`: `this.transitionToRoute(oldCurrentPath);`

But `transitionToRoute` is expecting `locators.index` instead of the full path `phoneNumbers.locators.index`:

```
Assertion failed: The route phoneNumbers.locators.index was not found 
Uncaught Error: There is no route named phoneNumbers.locators.index.index
```

(I do not know why ember tries `phoneNumbers.locators.index.index`)

Why is that? How can I "map" the path to the route? Must I maintain my own `PATH_TO_ROUTE_MAP` for that? That is what I have started doing, and it works, but surely `Ember` has a better way of doing this?

An alternative would be to catch the current route instead of the `currentPath`. Is this possible? How?

Comment: I believe Ember knows that locators is a nested resource of phoneNumbers, so it doesn't need the full path... See this chart on how nested resource route names are generated: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources

Comment: So in your case, the correct transition would be: `transitionToRoute('locators')` because of how you've named the nested resource. If you changed it to `this.resource('phoneNumbers.locators', function () {...` it would work with your `phoneNumbers.locators` route... Hopefully that makes sense. :)

Comment: I think you can also omit the `index` part of your route.

Comment: You mean that because of how I have structured the router, paths and routes are not the same in my application. So it is my mistake for not configuring the router *right* (but ember allows for this!) I didn't know that it is possible to name resources as you say. I will consider it, but I fear that changing my router configuration will have a huge effect in the naming of controllers/models/routes and who knows what other side-effects.

Comment: I would just leave your router as-is, and use transitionToRoute('locators')

Comment: Yes, thanks. I need to define the map then, since there are lots of routes affected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of caching the currentPath cache the targetName from the afterModel hook,

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(posts, transition) {
    //cache transition.targetName
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transition` object available in the hooks has some book-keeping about the paths it travels under `transition.router.currentHandlerInfos`.

You can get the previous state from there and cache them somewhere (maybe `applicationController` might be a better place) and then do a transition.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/KE4bp/1/)